# I'm finding I need to recreate class attributes in multiple un-related classes. Is my methodology wrong?

Tags: php, database-abstraction

Let's say I have 3 classes:

**User**

**Building**

**Car**

Each of these has their relevant properties. E.g.

**User** has name, age, email
**Building** has age, rooms, fire_alarm
**Car** has brand, seats, top_speed

Let's say I have a database that stores the relationship between a user and a building and a user and a car.

In my **Building** class, my *save_building* method requires the *user_id*.

I have two choices here.

**1)** I can either re-create the *user_id* property in the **Building** class (redundant and fragile and would need to be duplicated in the **Car** class too) or
**2)** I could just reference the user object directly and get the *user_id*.

Neither of these seem 'right'.

When I set my attributes, I validate them too and then store any errors of those validations in the object itself. If I use option **2**, I would have to check the other object for errors before allowing my save_building method to proceed rather than only having to check the object I'm working with.

Is option **1** the correct way forward or is option **2**?

Edit: For clarity, the database relationship tables are as follows:

user_buildings: user_id, building_id
user_cars: user_id, car_id

Edit2: Making the question non-open ended.

Comment: add a owner_id column for building and car, it should map to user_id ... or use car.owner_name/user.name

Comment: I have those in the relationship tables. I'm mainly wondering about how to handle the code side.

Comment: Why does your `save_building` method require `user_id`?

Comment: When I associate a user with a building, I need the user_id for when I store it in the database (in the user_buildings table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between users and buildings had to be stored in the database, so clearly is needs to manifest in your classes somehow.  There is nothing redundant about storing object references for the purpose of establishing the relationships of objects, so don't think that it is.  The only redundancy that could potentially be removed is having users and buildings pointing to each other versus only having one point to the other.  This is sort of like the question of whether one should use a singly-linked list versus a doubly-linked list.

Given your two options, I would prefer option 1, because in the case of User being unknown,  you can set it to `null` which is more semantic than `0` or `-1` or whatever integer equivalent in the case where the user was not queried/joined in the database or no relationships exist yet.

Another option which you didn't list is to have `save_building` ignorant of relationship changes between users and buildings.  Maybe this functionality should only be handled in the user class.  Maybe you want a new class building-owner class whose purpose is to handle this functionality.

Comment: How can the save_building method be made ignorant of user_id? If I push the save functionality to the user class then I have the opposite problem - I need to add a building_id property to the user class.

Comment: I don't see how there is any problem here.

Comment: Is it acceptable practice to have the building_id property in the user class?

Comment: The relationship clearly has to be stored somewhere.  It's acceptable to put it in users or buildings or in a class whose purpose is to establish relationships between users and buildings.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't feel quite right to me but I'll defer to your wisdom. Thanks.